# How to use variables defined in terraform.tfvars in main.tf

Tags: terraform

### structure in my terraform source

```
├── main.tf
├── outputs.tf
├── serverless
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   ├── variables.tf
│   └── versions.tf
├── variables.tf
└── versions.tf
```

### question

How can I use variables defined in terraform.tfvars in main.tf?
My code is based on this example and add the following code with it(replaced ~/examples/serverless with ~/serverless).

> terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds-aurora
> https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds-aurora

### code in serverless/terraform.tfvars

```
SAMPLE_VALUE="xxx"
```

### code in serverless/main.tf

```
variable "SAMPLE_VALUE" {}
```

### deploy command

```
$ terraform apply
```

### official document

It lacks of usage in other .tf file

> Variable Definitions (.tfvars) Files
> https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files

Comment: Did you try? Why it does not work? What errors do you get?

Comment: Thank you for a reasonable question. I tried and got an error as following.
`│ An argument named "SAMPLE_VALUE" is not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│ on main.tf line 51, in module "aurora_postgresql":
│ 51: SAMPLE_VALUE = var.SAMPLE_VALUE
`

Comment: The reason was that SAMPLE_VALUE wasn't defined in ~/main.tf.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your variable in variable file, you can use it in the same directory's main.tf with `var.` In your case, the variable you are trying to locate should be located to its place in `main.tf` using `var.SAMPLE_VALUE`

There is pretty clear explanation with example here ;

https://jhooq.com/terraform-variable-and-tfvars-file/#2-terraform-tfvars-file---terraformtfvars

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The point was declaration of `variable "SAMPLE_VALUE" {}` both serverless/main.tf and ~/main.tf, and I got an expected reply through `$terraform apply`

Comment: You didn't mention it because you have more than files named `main.tf` :) Anyway, happy to read you solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I succeeded to overcome this problem to define variable "SAMPLE_VALUE" {} both serverless/main.tf and ~/main.tf.
Thanks everyone for reply!!